# Csv file incorrectly loading in pandas csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have csv which I'm trying to load using `pd.read_csv`. However some lines of file are read as one column, while others are correctly read into separate columns.
I think the problem is with rows that contain quotes but i dont want to remove them.

I tried using quotechar but it does not help

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', sep=',', quotechar='"')
```

I'm providing you with csv content of the two rows, first one should read incorrectly while second one is correct:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14
a,br,c,,,,d,e,0,False,False,False,"bs,C",19/07/2018 23:25:12,27/05/2018 23:09:21
a,b,c,,,,d,e,2,False,False,False,U D,19/07/2011 11:21:02,18/07/2011 12:21:00
```

Since the example above works for others I'm providing a screenshot of what I get while trying to load csv file:
[image]

Comment: `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',', quotechar='"')` seems to read both of those rows into 14 columns

Comment: Somehow when you put it in csv file then it does not work properly

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: python ver. 3.7

Comment: This worked okay for me too.

Comment: Maybe I can send the csv file?

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. Pandas loads it fine. (using python 3.5)

Comment: Are you running python on a windows or a unix system?

Comment: which version of pandas package are you using? 0.25 works well
https://repl.it/repls/TightEthicalGraphs

Comment: For me your example data also seems to be imported correctly (I also use 0.25). I mean "bs,C" goes into one column. I didn't even have to specify quotechar. Do you maybe have some funny characters in your file? what is the encoding of the file?

Comment: So I checked and the file has cp1250 encoding. However passing this as an argument to pd.read_csv does not  solve th problem. I'm using 0.25 pandas as well.

Comment: I updated the question showing wierd behaviour of my csv file @murphy1310, I'm running on windows

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, just to clarfiy. What do you get, if you execute this code:

```
import io
raw="""
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14
a,br,c,,,,d,e,0,False,False,False,"bs,C",19/07/2018 23:25:12,27/05/2018 23:09:21
a,b,c,,,,d,e,2,False,False,False,U D,19/07/2011 11:21:02,18/07/2011 12:21:00
"""
df= pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(raw), sep=',')
df
```

If it looks ok, but the same lines create a problem in the csv, this is probably a encoding issue (which was removed by copying the text) and if so, probably you can resolve the whole issue by adding the appropriate `encoding=` option to `read_csv`.
On the other hand, if you can reproduce the problem on your machine with the code above, there is something weird going on, or your pandas version contains a bug. This is, because the code above works for me and from the comments on your question it seems that it also works for other people.

The output looks like this for me:

```
   0   1  2   3   4   5  6  7  8      9     10     11    12                   13                   14
0  a  br  c NaN NaN NaN  d  e  0  False  False  False  bs,C  19/07/2018 23:25:12  27/05/2018 23:09:21
1  a   b  c NaN NaN NaN  d  e  2  False  False  False   U D  19/07/2011 11:21:02  18/07/2011 12:21:00
```

So column "12" contains "bs,C" for the first record, which is correct, right?

Comment: The funny thing is if i save the csv file as txt then it reads the data correctly

Comment: What do you mean? So it imports the column correctly, but the corresponding lines ar not imported correctly from your file?

Comment: Yes when I read dirctly form .csv file then it doesnt work, copying code and using your code works correctly. But I need to use that csv file to read the data.

Comment: Then I'm pretty sure, it is an encoding issue. Just open the original csv in an editor like notepad++ or any other that displays the encoding, it detects and look what it thinks, it is. If it is utf8 also check if there is a BOM

Comment: ...then try to pass the detected encoding to `read_csv`. Or maybe if you can directly find out which encoding the wrting process uses, of course this would be a more reliable ressource than the editor method...

Comment: It's encoding is 'cp1250'

Comment: However passing it in the read_csv does not solve the problem `df = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', sep=',', quotechar='"', encoding='cp1250')`

Comment: Great. What happens if you call `pd.read_csv(...., encoding="cp1250")`?

Comment: Hmmm, that's strange. Maybe you could also try "windows-1250", but this is just a synonym.

Comment: Have you already checked https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings? maybe it contains some more info about that. If nothing helps and your files are not that big so you can read them into memory, you could maybe transcode them to Utf-8 and work with `io.StringIO` to read them into a dataframe afterwards.

Comment: Could you try, what happens, if you combine the `encoding` option with `engine='python'`? (but this probably slows down the reading process). Maybe the C-engine uses different code for the encoding.

Comment: I tried both and still not working. I even tried opening that file on different computers. Same problem happens everywhere.

Comment: From where do you know, it is "cp1250"? from the editor, or did you look it up? Sorry I'm running out of ideas. Just that you could play around with the following options `escapechar=''` (chose something that shouldn't occur in your file) and `index_col=False, skiprows=2, nrows=10` (the last 3 in combination to see if the rest of the file would be read correctly, or if the phenomenon just occurs always at the first data row that is read into the dataframe).

Comment: If you haven't done that already, probably it also helps to look at the file in a hex editor to see, whether there is an unprintable char, somwhere before the first data line, that spoils something.